# I still not clear about the publish.stream function.. help me please

Tags: facebook, authentication, publish

I still not clear about the publish.stream function.. Anybody please help me, how to setting up the app authentication, so that we can publish a new status update to our new app user.. thanks..

Answer (score 0):

You should always show us what you've tried and what is no working. Publishing to user's stream is one of the easiest things to do with graph api and a bit of reading of the documentation shows you exactly how:

Read about authentication - http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Read about permissions - http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/

Read about the news feed - http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

putting all those three together should be easy for anyone who has done a bit of web app development. Once you start and a particular thing is not working for you, you can post ask for help with the details, but no one here is going to write the code for you...

Comment: i have read these docs frequently, but i still not clear..

i just want to make a app like this:
1. users come to my webpage, and then they can't read the content before they signed in on my app (based on website)
2. after they loged in, they will see my content, and then the publish_stream permission will work to update their facebook status that they have read my content..

would you like to help me, give me a guide step by step?

i am confused where i must place the javascript/php code, where i setting up the status that will appear on my new app user etc.

Comment: 1.) you need user to log in so check out how to require users to be logged in; 2.) then check how to require user permissions (and which permissions you need) 3.) then check how to use graph api to post to user's news feed; split it into smaller steps always try to accomplish just one task; if you can't get on simple task working, post here with the details about what you're doing and what/why it doesn't work and include your code so that we see that you've tried something ...